# AppBar Registration shows Form shadow from main application form moved with AppBar after AutoHide switch

Tags: vb.net, winforms, appbar

I know that's dreadfully confusing, I will do my best to explain.

I have created an AppBar that Auto-Hides or Locks, same as the Windows one.  I have custom controls in the AppBar that do different things.

One of them simply moves our Deal Entry form from offscreen on, and off again (dual purpose button).  The Deal Entry form is not part of the AppBar, I communicate with it through a reference I set before I register it. When the button is pressed, I simply call a function in my main application form, and scroll it on/off screen via the main program.

If I have utilized this button to show or hide the Deal Entry form, and then switch my Auto-Hide (either direction), the Deal Entry form shadow appears, even though the Deal Entry form itself is offscreen and not visible.

There is *way* too much code here for me to post anything you would be able to reproduce - it's just too much.  I am linking a video showing the problem.

I understand that without code, this will be very difficult to diagnose, I am hoping that someone with AppBar experience has seen something similar.

I may just flip visibility in the parent reference once registration is complete, although that doesn't technically solve the problem, it just band-aids it.

Link to video: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yggxht00pzs76nm/2017-06-21-1428-02.mp4?dl=0

Comment: That is truly bizarre...  The Deal Entry form doesn't look quite "standard".   Are you using any third-party libraries for your controls or forms?  Did you make any low level calls to modify the window properties?  Are you doing any custom drawing on the form? Are you making the Deal Entry form a "child" of the AppBar through any API calls?

Comment: @Idle_Mind It is.  When I first started this program I used MahApps Metro forms. The deal entry system (it also has a companion) are the only things I used it on.  I do everything custom now.  But this is the first time I've ever seen a shadow problem with this form ever.  And it is 100% the toolbar registration causing it - it is super reproducible...